# C# WinForms. Implementing the property "Name" in the component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, components, windows-forms-designer

I would like to implement property `Name` in the `Component` that would have the same value as the name of a field in the Form that point to the component.

```
 private MyComponent myComponent1;
 this.myComponent1.Name = "myComponent1";
```

WinForms already implement such a property in `Control` class, but I can't understand how it works.

```
 private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
 this.button1.Name = "button1";
```

I think about declaring private string Name property in the MyComponentDesigner.
Or using ComponentRename event in the IComponentChangeService service.
Exploring source code of WinForms does not give an exact explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a simple `Name` property that shows in property grid, it's enough to add a trivial automatic get-set `Name` property to your component. But if you want your component have `Name` property and the `(Name)` property act like `(Name)` property of controls add the `Name` property this way:

```
string name;
[Browsable(false)]
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        if (Site != null)
            name = Site.Name;
        return name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Site != null)
            Site.Name = value;
        name = value;
    }
}
```

This way, you can get or set the `Name` property using code, or in property grid.  In property grid, when you assign a value to `(Name)` it will assign the `Name` property and the designer generates the component name assignment as well.

Comment: Thank you Reza.
It works as expected. 
Property Name is assigned by the name of the field that points to the myComponent.
But could you explain why this works or give a link where it is explained.
For me it looks like a magic code.
I tried to debug the Names.Set method through debugging devenv.exe. But it seems that Names.Set is never called in design-time.

Comment: You're welcome :) The implementation in Windows Forms is based on `Name` property of `Control`, `Name` property and `PrefilterProperties` method of `ControlDesigner`. I didn't try to implement the whole pattern, but tried to provide a simpler implementation which worked for me. In my implementation, private `name` field helps your component have name at run-time (In cases that you may create the `Component` without passing a container to its constructor). Also setting the `Site.Name` brings you the design-time desired behavior the same way that `Control` class has this behavior.

Comment: It became more clear, but not completely.

The main work is done in the Name.get method.
When VS implements the Name method in the code
and takes a value from the Name property.
At in design-time Site! = null, then the code name = Site.Name will work;
Site.Name is a real property name of the field that points to the component.
As a result, the code will be written down
this.myComponent1.Name = VS.myComponent1.Name.get (return Site.Name) = "myComponent1";

Comment: And what about the Name.set.
What is the code -
         if (Site! = null)
             Site.Name = value;
- for?
in the Name.set method.
When I debug devenv.exe the Name.set method looks like never called.

Comment: At design-time it seems it's not required, but for run-time, if you remove `if (Site != null) Site.Name = value;`  from setter, then at run-time create a component this way `var c = new Component1(components); c.Name = "XXX"; MessageBox.Show(c.Name);` the name would be empty! That's why I added that line of code.

Comment: Best (only) solution I've seen to date...  But I'll point out that during form construction, before it appears, the name will be set.  If other controls are constructed first and causes events that ask for this information, it will be blank.  But, once the form is fully loaded, the name will appear as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For others (like me) that prefer VB, here's the code:

```
Private _name As String
<Browsable(False)>
Public Property Name As String
    Get
        If Site IsNot Nothing Then _name = Site.Name
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Site IsNot Nothing Then Site.Name = value
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now, I added one more line so that calls for the Name that may occur very early -- before the name has been set -- don't get an empty response.  Here's my code:

```
Private _name As String
<Browsable(False)>
Public Property Name As String
    Get
        If Site IsNot Nothing Then
            _name = Site.Name
            If _name = String.Empty Then Return ToString()
        End If
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If Site IsNot Nothing Then Site.Name = value
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property
```